# Get specific / any CMS page title

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-pages, page-title

I would like to retrieve a specific page name in my frontend phtml on magento `v1.9.2.4`. I have found many ways to retrieve 'current' page title, such as thoses questions posted on stackoverflow :

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950370/how-to-get-page-title-in-magento
- [Get the meta description and page title of any page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102351/get-the-meta-description-and-page-title-of-any-page)

but this is not what I want. I need to show this title in a 'call-to-action' fashion which will be used elsewhere on the website.

**EDIT 2017-01-04 - I found a solution, please view my post below**

Comment: If it can help anyone : I found a solution below, it works anywhere on the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with the identifier there is the easiest way to do it:

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('PAGEIDENTIFIERHERE', 'identifier')->getTitle(); ?>
```

Comment: thank you @Dynomite, For me i am using following function to get current cms page title
<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getTitle(); ?>